# TLS settings for Kafka Producer with PEM files

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, tls1.2

Is there a way to configure TLS in Kafka Producer with pem files? I'm using [Apache Kafka Stream library](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#clients).
My problem is that I have only pem files, in particular cert.pem , privkey.pem, and ca.pem but, from documentation, I can see that Keystore and Trustore can be set only with jks files. I'm using Scala language.

Comment: The page you link says ssl.truststore.type _defaults_ to JKS; that implies it can be set to any value [supported by Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keystore-types) (which might vary depending on your Java installation or runtime config). You can create a PKCS12 from PEM files with appropriate content such as your names indicate using `openssl pkcs12 -export`; there are dozens of Qs on multiple stacks covering this (and it isn't really a programming or development question). ...

Comment: ... Alternatively https://keystore-explorer.org/ can directly read PEM files with suitable content into any Java keystore type (including the ones added by BouncyCastle).

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.7.0 apache kafka supports providing the certificates in PEM format

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10338

For the client you need to provide this props

```
SslConfigsSslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION  
/var/ssl/private/ca.pem
        

setProperty(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, "PEM");
```

Anyways just for your information,  creating JKS (Java Key Store) it just matter of doing one or two command... you might want to explore that

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/security_tutorial.html#generating-keys-certs

For mutual authentication mtls you'll need to provide keystore which is your private certificate signed by your ca, and truststore which is your ca bundle, if you are using PEM , keys not need to be provided as PEM is not secured by password, the key for truststore/keystore is the password of your jks files

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/configure-mds/mutual-tls-auth-rbac.html

Comment: Hi, for the mutual authentication I need to set also "SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION", right? My dubt is if this parameter considers a PEM file composed by certificate+private key. Because I have 2 different PEM files for each one.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to set "SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION" providing a PEM file containing cert+private key. But this configuration gives me an error "Generic Exception - Unable to publish data on KAFKA Error: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer".

Comment: If I set the properties in this way :         .withProperties(Map(
          "security.protocol" -> "SSL",
          "ssl.keystore.type" -> "PEM",
          "ssl.keystore.key" -> "/run/secrets/cert/client/cliprivkey.pem",
          "ssl.keystore.certificate.chain" -> "/run/secrets/cert/client/clicert.pem",
          "ssl.truststore.type" -> "PEM",
          "ssl.truststore.certificates" -> "/run/secrets/ca/default/cacertbundle.pem"
        ))

Comment: I obtain a different error : "Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: For mutual authentication mtls you'll need to provide keystore which is your private certificate signed by your ca, and truststore which is your ca bundle, if you are using PEM , keys not need to be provided as PEM is not secured by password, the key for truststore/keystore is the password of your jks files